# How to do a 10% 45% 45% Split in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, split

I am trying to figure out how to do a 10% 45% 45% split in SQL Server. I have come up with a way using `NTile` to assign a group and then splitting the groups based on simple math but the solution falls down when less than 20 records are identified

```
SELECT
    Email, 
    CASE 
       WHEN Group in (1,2) THEN 'Group1'
       WHEN Group BETWEEN 3 AND 11 THEN 'Group2'
       WHEN Group BETWEEN 12 AND 20 THEN 'Group3'
    END AS [Group]
FROM
   (SELECT
        email, optDate, 
        NTILE(20) OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) As Group) T
```

I also having the annoying problem of not being able to use temp tables or create variables, my solution has to begin with a select statement. I can create result steps in stages and use the results of say stage 1 in a query for stage 2 but I am having a hard time coming up with a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I approach these problems using explicit counting and numbers.  The following uses `newid()` to assign a sequence of numbers randomly.  The rest is just arithmetic:

```
SELECT Email,
       (CASE WHEN seqnum <= cnt * 0.10 THEN 'Group1'
             WHEN seqnum <= cnt * (0.10 + 0.45) THEN 'Group2'
             ELSE 'Group3'
        END) as [Group]
FROM (SELECT email, optDate, 
             row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      FROM t
     ) t;
```

As a note:  there is some discussion that says that `checksum(newid())` is actually better for random ordering than just `newid()`.  (And even others that recommend `rand(checksum(newid()))`).  For your purposes, any of these will probably suffice.

Comment: Nice solution! I think you have one typo and meant to have 0.10 instead of 0.05 in the 2 places where 0.05 is referenced.

Comment: @BateTech . . . Thank you for finding that.

Answer (score 2):

`Row_Number` should be enough

```
WITH A AS (
  SELECT TOP 1000000
         email, optDate
       , ID = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY email, optDate)
       , Items = COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY (Select 1))
  FROM   myTable
  ORDER BY NEWID()
)
SELECT
    Email, 
    CASE 
       WHEN ID < Items * 0.1 THEN 'Group1'
       WHEN ID < Items * 0.55 THEN 'Group2'
       ELSE 'Group3'
    END AS [Group]
FROM A
```

In multiplier of the `CASE` be sure to add the values of the group below the current one to get the correct results (the second group goes from Items * 0.10 to Item * 0.55 the difference is Items * 0.45).

The `TOP` in the `CTE` is necessary to get the `ORDER BY`, as `TOP 100%` will not actually the resultset ordered you have to use a number at least equal to the number of rows returned by the query.

If you cannot use even `CTE`s substitute the A in the main query with a subquery with the same definition:

```
SELECT
    Email, 
    CASE 
       WHEN ID < Items * 0.1 THEN 'Group1'
       WHEN ID < Items * 0.55 THEN 'Group2'
       ELSE 'Group3'
    END AS [Group]
FROM (SELECT TOP 1000000
             email, optDate
           , ID = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY email, optDate)
           , Items = COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY (Select 1))
      FROM   myTable
      ORDER BY NEWID()
     ) A
```